# How can I create a simple signed certificate for my Windows Forms .NET app in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: certificate, self-signed

I published my app and it worked on my developer pc but when i installed the app on another pc, the installation went well, but when I started the app, it hangs.
I suspect I need a (self signed) certificate. Anyone ?
My app is developed for a friend and will NOT go to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do some logging in the app to confirm the reason for the hanging issue.
If the issue is related to the certificate, then the app should not run successfully at all.
If the app can run successfully but it hangs half way, then probably the reason for the hanging issue is not related to the certification.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd check that all required libraries and dependencies are installed on the target PC (Similar to your environment). Also, you can try running the app as an administrator to avoid potential permission issues.

If that doesn't work, then try running your program in debug mode on the target PC to catch any errors that may be happening.

---

Usually, an app won't hang due to lacking a self-signed certificate unless your system has strict policies on unsigned certificates. (Which shouldn't be the case here)